# Ruby - Scraper concatenate strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, web-scraping, concatenation, scraper

I'm making a Ruby web scraper to gather some info.
In the HTML of the page that I want to scrape, there are 3 equal spans per article:

```
<article>
   <div class="item item_contains_branding" data-adid="1234567">
      <div class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
         <div class="item-multimedia ">
            ...
         </div>
         <div class="item-info-container">
            <div class="logo-branding">
            ...
            </div>
                    <a href="/link/1" class="item-link " title="title 1" data-xiti-click="listado::enlace">title 1</a> 
            <div class="row price-row clearfix"> <span class="item-price">200<span>€</span></span> </div>
            <span class="item-detail">T2 <small></small></span> <span class="item-detail">20 <small>m²</small></span> <span class="item-detail"> <small> more details 1</small></span> 
                <p class="item-description">description...</p>
            <div class="item-toolbar clearfix">
            ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
<article>
   <div class="item item_contains_branding" data-adid="1234567">
      <div class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
         <div class="item-multimedia ">
            ...
         </div>
         <div class="item-info-container">
            <div class="logo-branding">
            ...
            </div>
                    <a href="/link/2" class="item-link " title="title 2" data-xiti-click="listado::enlace">title 2</a> 
            <div class="row price-row clearfix"> <span class="item-price">300<span>€</span></span> </div>
            <span class="item-detail">T5 <small></small></span> <span class="item-detail">50 <small>m²</small></span>
                <p class="item-description">description...</p>
            <div class="item-toolbar clearfix">
            ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
<article>
   <div class="item item_contains_branding" data-adid="1234567">
      <div class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
         <div class="item-multimedia ">
            ...
         </div>
         <div class="item-info-container">
            <div class="logo-branding">
            ...
            </div>
                    <a href="/link/3" class="item-link " title="title 3" data-xiti-click="listado::enlace">title 3</a> 
            <div class="row price-row clearfix"> <span class="item-price">500<span>€</span></span> </div>
            <span class="item-detail">T1 <small></small></span> <span class="item-detail">100 <small>m²</small></span> <span class="item-detail"> <small> more details 3</small></span> 
                <p class="item-description">description...</p>
            <div class="item-toolbar clearfix">
            ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

However, some of the articles don't have the last span (with "more details")

For now, I have been using this code:

```
#first loop to find the title
page.css('a.item-link').each do |line|
    puts line.text
end
#Second loop to find the price
page.css('span.item-price').each do |line|
    puts line.text
end
#third loop to find the details
page.css('span.item-detail').each do |line|
    line.text
end
```

I'm using the Nokogiri gem and open-uri to retrieve and parse the file.

How can I concatenate the 3 spans (some articles only have two spans in the "item-detail" class) and print them in the screen?

My desired output is:

```
title 1
title 2
title 3
200€
300€
500€
T2
T5
T1
20 m²
50 m²
100 m²
more details 1
" "
more details 3
```

Some of the articles don't have the third span (with "more details n") so if that is the case i will print " ". My goal is to write the results to a .csv file

Comment: Please edit your question to include your desired output.

Comment: Maybe look into `reduce`

Comment: OK, I see that the question has changed, and there's expected output now.  The expected output doesn't correlate to the input HTML at all.  There are no title, price, or details in the example, so there's literally no way to satisfactorily answer the question.  Please provide suitable (realistic) input and examples of which portions of the input you expect to be matched to which portions of the output.  As I say, the way the question is not is not answerable.

Comment: @Michael Gaskill, first of all, thanks for your help. I've changed the input so it will be more easy to analyse.

Comment: With your new input, I still don't see how to get `details 1 (first span)`, `details 2 (first span)`, etc.  What is the difference between `details N` and `Nth span`?  The input only has 3 spans matching `item-details`, yet you ask for 9 outputs.  Where does all of this missing information come from?

Comment: And when you say that you want the spans concatenated for printing, are they to be concatenated with spaces, newlines, or what, exactly?  Do the spans get prefixed with any text, for instance, "title ", "price ", or "details ", or are the raw contents of the spans simply concatenated directly together into a span soup?  What part of the output is the actual span contents, which are the prefix (or suffix), and which separators are you expecting?  Please be very specific, and show example output based exactly on your input.

Comment: sorry about the poor explanation, i think now you can understand the input vs the output. thanks once again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that works for the sample input, although I had to modify the input XML slightly to be contained within a single HTML node (`<document>`) to be properly parseable:

```
require "nokogiri"

html = <<HTML
<document>
<article>
   <div class="item item_contains_branding" data-adid="1234567">
      <div class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
         <div class="item-multimedia ">
            ...
         </div>
         <div class="item-info-container">
            <div class="logo-branding">
            ...
            </div>
                    <a href="/link/1" class="item-link " title="title 1" data-xiti-click="listado::enlace">title 1</a>
            <div class="row price-row clearfix"> <span class="item-price">200<span>€</span></span> </div>
            <span class="item-detail">T2 <small></small></span> <span class="item-detail">20 <small>m²</small></span> <span class="item-detail"> <small> more details 1</small></span>
                <p class="item-description">description...</p>
            <div class="item-toolbar clearfix">
            ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
<article>
   <div class="item item_contains_branding" data-adid="1234567">
      <div class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
         <div class="item-multimedia ">
            ...
         </div>
         <div class="item-info-container">
            <div class="logo-branding">
            ...
            </div>
                    <a href="/link/2" class="item-link " title="title 2" data-xiti-click="listado::enlace">title 2</a>
            <div class="row price-row clearfix"> <span class="item-price">300<span>€</span></span> </div>
            <span class="item-detail">T5 <small></small></span> <span class="item-detail">50 <small>m²</small></span>
                <p class="item-description">description...</p>
            <div class="item-toolbar clearfix">
            ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
<article>
   <div class="item item_contains_branding" data-adid="1234567">
      <div class="clearfix" style="display: block;">
         <div class="item-multimedia ">
            ...
         </div>
         <div class="item-info-container">
            <div class="logo-branding">
            ...
            </div>
                    <a href="/link/3" class="item-link " title="title 3" data-xiti-click="listado::enlace">title 3</a>
            <div class="row price-row clearfix"> <span class="item-price">500<span>€</span></span> </div>
            <span class="item-detail">T1 <small></small></span> <span class="item-detail">100 <small>m²</small></span> <span class="item-detail"> <small> more details 3</small></span>
                <p class="item-description">description...</p>
            <div class="item-toolbar clearfix">
            ...
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
</document>
HTML

page  = Nokogiri::XML(html)
articles = page.css('article')

articles.each do |article|
  article.css('a.item-link').each do |link|
    puts "#{link[:title]}"
  end
end

articles.each do |article|
  article.css('span.item-price').each do |price|
    puts "#{price.text}"
  end
end

articles.each do |article|
  detail_spans = article.css('span.item-detail')
  puts "#{detail_spans[0].text}"
end

articles.each do |article|
  detail_spans = article.css('span.item-detail')
  puts "#{detail_spans[1].text}"
end

articles.each do |article|
  detail_spans = article.css('span.item-detail')
  puts "#{detail_spans[2] ? detail_spans[2].text.strip : ' '.inspect }"
end
```

This code retrieves an array of the `article` elements, and then uses each article element in the array to scope additional queries for elements contained within.  This gives the ability to do fine-grained reporting of individual element values.

The final `item-detail` query uses element detection to determine how to output the values in the presence of elements that may not exist.  Other queries may require such a technique, depending on the actual HTML document contents.

These are the results:

```
title 1
title 2
title 3
200€
300€
500€
T2 
T5 
T1 
20 m²
50 m²
100 m²
more details 1
" "
more details 3
```

Comment: with your method the output gets better but i want to separate the "item-detail" and print all the first span of all the articles, next the second span of all the articles and if the article has third span print it, if it doesn't print ""

Comment: @absint0o I was able to get the Nokogiri parser working as you described.  The additional detail was very helpful.  Thank you!  Check out the answer and let me know if you have questions or need any clarification.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help! now i'm getting the error: 
imov_scrap.rb:28:in `block in <main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @absint0o The last paragraph in my answer, directly above the results describes that you might need to use element detection to use values that don't exist.  This is one of those cases.  Look at the very last block of code in the sample that I wrote that uses the ternary operator to check if `detail_spans[2]` exists, and only uses the `text` method on it if it does.  That's the solution to this problem that you've found.

Comment: So great to hear.  Upvotes are always welcome!  :D  Good luck with your project!